# Hecke Character vs Grossencharakter

Tags: elliptic-curves, characters, complex-multiplication

I would like to know if there is any difference between 
(1) an algebraic Hecke character
(2) a Hecke character
(3) a Grössencharakter
All of the above in the setting of ellitpic curves with complex multiplication. Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what that means "in the setting of elliptic curves with CM".

Comment: What I meant to say was that in elliptic curves, we have associated grossencharacters and hecke characters. So the question is: are they different? Or are they just different names for the same thing?

Comment: Grossencharacters are "grossen" in that they have infinite order. Sometimes "Hecke characters" only means ones of finite order. From the adelic standpoint, authors are less likely to make a distinction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grossencharacters and Hecke characters are different names for the same thing.